# Event Trigger Is not Function

Tags: javascript, datetime, pagination, eventtrigger

In the pagination grid we are using key up change event function for filter the table values. In that Key up change event working fine but after getting the filter result if i click the edit button it doesn't working on first time  i need one more time to click the button to edit the form.
In that issue i got the solution for this by using only key up event function instead of key up change function. But in that i faced an one more issue,the date time picker does not work on filter due to this key up event function. How do i resolve this issue?

```
function LoadData() {
    debugger
    dataTable.getData();
    $("th input[type=text]").on('keyup', function () {

        dataTable.otable
            .column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: @Fildor indeed, I have submitted an edit without the tag an rewording a bit the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You add the date picker change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ76b.png)